# Node.js - how to use a raw request body using Express

Tags: node.js, json, express, middleware, body-parser

so I was making a RESTful API and I wanted to be able to receive raw json data (so I can use my api for mobile too), then from there save the data into my database (mongoDB).

But you see, there is this problem which I can't seem to fix and its that I'm not able to use the raw data as a json.

The code is simple

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.raw({inflate:true, limit: '100kb', type: 'application/json'});


app.post('/post', function(req, res){
 res.send(parse.JSON(req.body));
//to convert it to json but this doesn't seem to work
})
```

PS. I'm using postman to send the request as raw format

Comment: What is `parse.JSON()`.  Do you mean `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: It's unclear why you have to use `express.raw()` for mobile.  That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.raw({inflate:true, limit: '100kb', type: 'application/json'});


app.post('/post', function(req, res){
 res.send(JSON.parse(req.body));
})
```

inside the res.send you have to use JSON.parse() instead of parse.JSON() which will throw an error as it is not correct

if you want to read more about JSON.parse you can visit [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: And, you need error handling if the JSON is invalid.  But, it's completely unclear why the OP is manually parsing the JSON themselves.  `express.json()` will work just fine and has built-in error handling.

Comment: can do, but maybe he is experimenting with the code to learn new things, there can be many possibilities

Comment: Writing additional code without error handling for the wrong reasons is not something we want to recommend here.  So, good answers try to get to the bottom of what the real problem to be solved here is in order to actually make the best recommendation for the real issue.  And, yes, sometimes the best recommendation is to not do it this way.  The OP mentions doing this "so I can use my api for mobile too" which makes NO sense at all.  That's not a good reason to do this manually without any error handling.

Comment: Anyways, seems like the fault was on me all along. I was using the wrong code format which was "parse.JSON" instead of "JSON.parse" and now it works fine.

Comment: @Douo he is just helping you understand the concept, there can be 2 type of solution to a problem, 1- the correct was to do it, 2- the wrong way but with right output(which can create issue down the line)

Comment: ...and when I said "use my api for mobile too", I was saying that I will be using the API in my mobile app using http.post(...) pkg (flutter) therefore to allow the mobile app to post data to the DB through the API. It can be confusing to understand what I'm saying but the end point is that I want to post data using my API and I plan to do so by sending a raw json format (since I can't use the urlencoded format for my mobile - to get data from the mobile unlike html forms) and using flutter http package

Comment: @ShivamUttam sure thing man 

Answer (score 1):

`var app = express();`

This is going to work with the newest update.

```
app.post("/w/wht", express.raw({ type: '*/*' }), function (req, res) {

  console.log("last", req.body.toString())
})
```

This code sets up a route in a Node.js/Express application using the app.post() method. The route is listening for HTTP POST requests to the /w/wht endpoint.

The route handler function takes two parameters: req (short for request) and res (short for response).

The express.raw() middleware is used to parse the request body as raw binary data, regardless of its content type.

Inside the route handler function, console.log() is used to print out the contents of the request body, which is obtained using req.body.toString(). The toString() method is called to convert the raw binary data to a string, so that it can be logged to the console.

Overall, this code sets up a route that logs the contents of the HTTP POST request body as a string to the console.

Comment: Do you know what `req.body.toString()` actually does?  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, tried it and it works. It represents the data submitted in a HTTP request body. The toString() method is used to convert the body data to a string.

Comment: raw parser makes `req.body` return Buffer object. `.toSttring()` will return the text representation.